# javascript/jquery why does taken string not hold as a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codemirror

i try to get the "name" attribute from an element and use that string to call a already existing variable.

thats the html (the li's are function's target):::

```
<ul name="editor">
    <li><a href="#">Politics</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Finance</a></li>
</ul>
```

getting name and use it on function "getCursor":::***THIS DOES NOT WORK, WHY***

```
var messa = $(item).parent().attr("name"); //getting name which is "editor"
start_cursor = messa.getCursor()
```

atm it only works if i **"hardcode"** the variable like this:

```
start_cursor = editor.getCursor()
```

"editor" is predefined like this (Codemirror):

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), 
{mode: "javascript"});
```

i want to make it dynamically by getting the stringname from ul.

thanks for your time and wisdom

Comment: What do you get when you type `typeof messa` or `messa === editor`? `messa` is a string, not an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To switch from a string to something defined in javascript, try

```
objectTheVarIsDefinedIn[nameOfVariable]
```

In this case I'm not sure which object/scope/function you used, I guess the general scope which would be

```
window[messa].getCursor();
```

or maybe you used a function, and you're still on the same level:

```
this[messa].getCursor();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because something has the same name doesn't name doesn't make it the same thing. By your logic I could name something document and it would be the document.

```
var mydoc = "document";
mydoc.location; //won't work because mydoc is just a string, it isn't the document object.
```

Comment: not really the point here. more like this. instead of using document.body i would get the name from an element which is "document", save it in a variable "habanot" and call the object instead habanot.body.

Comment: But `messa` is a string. `getCursor()` is not a method of a string. So you can't call it like that.

Comment: yeah but can't a string be converted to a variable? like a variable variable? something like eval("dynamic" + i + " = val[i]");

Comment: Maybe you should explain in your question what you are trying to do (big picture). What you are currently attempting doesn't make sense. Using eval to convert a string into a variable is a bad idea. There are better ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

`messa` in this case is a string. You can't call getCursor() on a string.

however, `editor` in this case is now a property of the window object, so you could do this:

```
window[messa].getCursor();
```